# Боковая навигация

Tags: android

Занимаюсь разработкой нового приложения. Решила использовать **боковую навигацию** (Типа как в ВКонтакте). Нашла несколько примеров, даже готовые проекты на github. Но все они слишком навороченные. Может кто-то знает хороший и понятный пример с объяснением. Буду рада простому и понятному проекту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одной из последних версий библиотеки android  support library добавили компонент navigation drawer. Это то что вам нужно http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip

Answer (score 0):

[HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)  правда с наворотами, но есть хороший демо пример

---

[подключение в  eclipse](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE#eclipse)  если случайно не заметила, мои последующие советы по сути и есть один большой бубен, следовать им можно, но с большой оглядкой и если сроки не горят то стоит разобраться с maven, если уже то я пока делаю так:

1. с помощью git клонирую проект
2. импортирую его, как maven проект
3. скорее всего пропатчить support library  можно и из плагина, не нашел как поэтому поставил maven прописал пути в puth, по идеи дальше  смотрим в ман установки и радуемся, но увы у меня что то не получилось поэтому скачал  [support-v4-13.0.1.jar](https://github.com/Prototik/ActionBarSherlock-Repo/raw/master/com/android/support/support-v4/13.0.1/support-v4-13.0.1.jar) 
   и в папке с скачанным файлом прописал вот такую команду(все в одну строчку) mvn install:install-file -Dfile=support-v4-13.0.1.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=support-v4 -Dversion=r13.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
   дальше по ману
   я использовал intellj idea, может в eclipse будет как то по другому

Comment: нет, там многомодульный проект, demo это модуль проекта демонстрирующий возможности библиотеки, как правильно добавить в готовый проект пока сказать не могу - сам только начал начал с ней разбираться, можно по идеи обойтись без maven и скачать готовые jar файлы из maven репризитория, но подозреваю что танцев с бубном будет только больше (

Comment: @gadfil, какие-то проекты все намудренные, я уже весь день с бубном танцую... :(

Comment: повторюсь, сам с maven и HoloEverywhere столкнулся только пару дней назад, все советы воспринимать критично - не хочу плохому учить ))

Comment: @gadfil, меня бы хоть плохому научили)) 
как раз бьюсь щас над подключением в eclipse как описано на сайте github. проблема сразу вываливается на первом пункте. не получается установить EGit Plugin, постоянно вываливается ошибка... вот и беда

Comment: уходи с eclipse)) или не используй плагин, а пиши в консоли ( но с eclipse все рано уйдешь ;) )

Comment: @gadfil, ну может и уйду) но год надо на нем досидеть (практику сдавать скоро), сдать диплом а там посмотрю)))

Answer (score 0):

Делал простой пример навигации с новым гугловым компонентом, там есть дровер, кода немного, должно быть понятно:
https://github.com/AlexeySAntonov/AndroidNavigationComponent