# Как сделать выдвижную панель в приложении

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Как сделать в приложении выдвижную панель вроде такой?

[image: img]
Она ещё открывается, когда пользователь ведёт по экрану слева направо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вначале смотрим на это: [`Navigation Drawer`](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). Убеждаемся, что это то, что нужно. А потом идем [сюда (Creating a Navigation Drawer)](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) и применяем.

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

[Боковая навигация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237580/android-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)